# Pulling data out of NSMutableDictionary and adding to a different NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, ios4, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

**SETUP**

I have a NSMutableDictionary with over 800 NSMutableDictionaries in it representing employees.  I am trying to implement a search bar and i am having serious issues working with my dictionaries.

In the first For Loop i cread a dictionary for searching, and in the send i am attempting to search each employee in that dictionary.

**PROBLEM**

How can i add an individual dictionary to a new dictionary to hold all the dictionaries with the search term in it?

```
- (void) searchTableView:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar  {

NSString *searchText = theSearchBar.text;
NSMutableDictionary *searchDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *employee in employeeData)
{
    [searchDict setValue:employee forKey:[employee objectForKey:kFULLNAME_TAG]];
}

for (NSDictionary *emp in searchDict)
{
    NSString *empName = [emp objectForKey:kFULLNAME_TAG]; 
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [empName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length > 0){
        NSLog(@"search result ---> %@" ,emp);
        [copyListOfItems setValue:empName forKey:emp];
    }
}
}
```

In the second For Loop, I am having trouble with the copyListOfItems setValue:empName forKey:emp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your parameters backwards when inserting into your `copyListOfItems` (which I'm assuming is an NSMutableDictionary ivar in your class?).  The employee object should be the value and the employee name should be the key.

```
[copyListOfItems setValue:emp forKey:empName];
```

You shouldn't need to use two loops to accomplish what you need though.  This would be simpler:

```
for (NSDictionary *emp in employeeData)
{
    NSString *empName = [emp objectForKey:kFULLNAME_TAG]; 
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [empName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.location != NSNotFound){
        [copyListOfItems setValue:emp forKey:empName];
    }
}
```